# Is the point on the left or the right of the vector in 2D space?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

I'm trying to find if one point on the left or the right of a 2D vector.
Example, looking to the figure below; I have the 2D points for **a,b** and **c** in the two cases. I'm try to find whether **c** is located on the left or right of the vector **ab**. 
[image]
How can we find that mathematically?

Comment: One way to do this is to use the cross product.  Look at the vector $b-a$ and $c-a$ (as vectors in three dimensions) and take their cross product.  The sign of the cross product will tell you which side $c$ is on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a=(a_x,a_y)$, $b=(b_x,b_y)$, and $c=(c_x,c_y)$ be points in the plane.  Consider the vectors $b-a=(b_x-a_x,b_y-a_y)$ and $c-a=(c_x-a_x,c_y-a_y)$.  Now, think of these vectors as vectors in three dimensions, i.e., 
$$
b-a=(b_x-a_x,b_y-a_y,0)\quad\text{and}\quad c-a=(c_x-a_x,c_y-a_y,0).
$$
Take the cross product $(b-a)\times (c-a)$, the result will be a vector of the form $(0,0,d)$.  The sign of $d$ tells you on which side of $b-a$ the point $c$ lies.

For example, let $a=(0,0)$, $b=(1,0)$, and $c=(0,1)$.  Then, $c$ lies to the left of the vector $(b-a)$.  Now, as above, $b-a=(1,0,0)$ and $c-a=(0,1,0)$.  Then the cross product $(b-a)\times(c-a)=(0,0,1)$.

Alternately, if you use $c=(4,-2)$, then $c$ lies to the right of $(b-a)$.  In this case, $c-a=(4,-2,0)$ and the cross product $(b-a)\times(c-a)=(0,0,-2)$.

Comment: I agree with this approach, though I'd stress that it's possible to work it out in two dimensions, the idea being that "beings" in two dimensional place can tell which way they are spinning even without realizing that they are in a part of three dimensional space.

Comment: @GPerez, well, since only the last element of the cross product is relevant, you can shorten the calculation as follows. You also don't need to expand the vectors to three dimensions.
$$
\text{with}\\
T = c- a\\
D = b- a\\
$$
The result becomes

$
\text{sgn} (D_1 T_2 - D_2 T_1)
$.
And thank you, Michael! I have had this problem pop up a number of times, and until now I had only sub-optimal solutions, that bothered me a lot.