# Proof of using dot product to determine which side of a vector a point is on

Tags: geometry

For illustration sake.

Lets set $r=[3,3]$ and $s=[4,8]$

Given points $r$,$s$ and a vector $\underline v$,

How do I prove that the point $r$ is on one side of the plane?

I know that you can use a dot product to prove this.

For example, if $r\cdot\underline v > 0$ it is on one side of the vector. If $r\cdot\underline v < 0$, it is on the other side.

The intuition seems logical to me but I cannot seem to prove it myself with real working numbers and examples.

Can anyone prove it to me? I have looked at other similar questions but I cannot seem to understand them.

Comment: $(1,0)\cdot(1,1)=(1,0)\cdot(1,-1)$. As well, $r\cdot v$ is positive if the angle between the vectors is acute, negative if it’s obtuse, but it doesn’t care about the sign of the angle, so what do you mean by “one side of the vector?”

Comment: If your vector is a bound vector [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232773/is-the-point-on-the-left-or-the-right-of-the-vector-in-2d-space) should do the job.

Comment: The dot product's value is not changed if you rotate the vectors so that one of them lies on the $x$ axis. So without loss of generality, assume one of the vectors is $(a, 0)$ (where $a > 0$), and the other is $(b, c)$. Then the result is clear: the dot product of these vectors is simply $ab$, which is positive if and only if $b > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

[image: VecDot]

---

Perhaps what you mean is that $v$ defines a halfplane: $v$ is orthogonal
to the line bounding the halfplane. Let me assume the halfplane line
passes through the origin. Then when $p \cdot v > 0$, $p$ lies in the
positive halfplane. When $p \cdot v < 0$, it lies on the negative side.
And $p \cdot v = 0$ defines the halfplane bounding line.

Comment: Yes this is what i meant. I am not sure am i duplicating questions but this is the greater context of my question. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/75087/using-random-projections-for-locally-sensitive-hashing